# How to call a http Observable inside a subscription to another Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a subject that is subscribed to and fires when a user searches.

```
let searchView;
this.searchSubject
      .switchMap((view: any) => {
          searchView = view;
          this.http.post(this.url, view);
      })
      .subscribe(page => {
          this.searchHistoryService.addRecentSearch(searchView).subscribe();
      })
```

searchHistoryService.addRecentSearch records this search so the user can see their recent searches.

I don't think this is good practice as the observable is subscribed to everytime, I would rather use a subject which I'm calling .next() on, or combine the history call with the search call itself.

If searchHistoryService.addRecentSearch returns a Subject I can call .next() but where would I subscribe to it?

I tried adding this in the searchHistoryService's constructor

```
this.searchHistorySubject.do(observableIWantToCall()).subscribe()
```

and then replacing the subscription to 'addRecentSearch' with this:

```
this.searchHistoryService.searchHistorySubject.next(searchView)
```

But it doesnt work.

The inner observable, observableIWantToCall() gets called but the observable returned isnt subscribed to.

What's wrong with this and what is best practice for subscribing to an observable when another is finished emitting?

Comment: Use `.switchMap(..).concatMap(page => this.searchHistoryService.addRecentSearch(searchView)).subscribe()`

Comment: The issue with this is that the subscribe returns the result of 'addRecentSearch', not the results of the observable in switchMap

Comment: I changed the order to have the call i wanted results as last, and used flatMap to combine them

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
let searchView;
private searchHistorySubject$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor(){
   this.searchHistoryService.addRecentSearch(searchView).first().subscribe(
     response => {
        //It will entry when you send data through next
     },
     error => {
       console.log(error);
     }
   );
}

...

addRecentSearch(searchView) {
    ...
    return this._searchHistorySubject$.asObservable();
}

setSearchHistoryEvent(value: any) {
  this._searchHistorySubject$.next(value);
}

this.searchSubject
      .switchMap((view: any) => {
          searchView = view;
          this.http.post(this.url, view);
      })
      .subscribe(page => {
          this.searchHistoryService.setSearchHistoryEvent(searchView);
      }
)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I want an observable inside the addRecentSearch to fire, so if inside the subscription i have this.http.get.('')subscribe() then that will be subscribed to every time

Comment: You can manage the subscription using first(). It will take the first response.

Comment: I dont think that is what the question asks, where you have "//It will entry when you send data through next" I want to have the equivalent of this.http.get().sunscribe(), but this is a bad idea as it will subscribe every time and that can lead to memory leaks, so i should be calling next on a subject, or combining the observables to fire together